# PHP - Need help with some string functions

Tags: php

I am trying to write a script to pull schedule data out of a database used at work.

The employees working times are stored daily as a string like this

```
000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000
```

Every character represents 15 min.  The first character space is 12:00 AM second is 12:15 AM and so on....

The example above the employee works 8:00 - 6:00.

I created an array like this for every character position.

```
$time[0] = "12:00";
$time[1] = "12:15";
$time[2] = "12:30";
$time[3] = "12:45";
$time[4] = "1:00";
$time[5] = "1:15";
$time[6] = "1:30";
$time[7] = "1:45";
$time[8] = "2:00";
```

and I can display the employees time like this

```
echo $time[strpos($string, '1')] . "-" . $time[strpos($string, '0', strpos($string, '1'))];
```

but I cannot figure out how to make this work if someone has a split shift, such as 9:30 - 2:00 / 4:00 - 7:00

```
000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111110000000011111111111110000000000000000000
```

Sorry if my English is poor.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need to handle split shifts like that, you might as well just solve it in the general case, iterate over each character.

Something like this:

```
<?PHP
$date = '2010-09-24'; // or whatever.

$string = '00000000001111100000001111...';

//convert your string in to an array
$data = explode('',$string); 

$time = strtotime("$date 00:00:00"); //midnight on whatever day $date is

$workstate = 0; // zero means not working, 1 means working.
foreach($data as $index=>$value){
    // employee started working
    if ($value && ! $workstate){ 
        $state = 1;
        echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$time) .'-';
    }
    // employee stopped working
    if ($workstate && ! $value){
        $state = 0;
        echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$time) . PHP_EOL;
    }
    $time = strtotime('+15 minutes', $time); increase time by 15 minutes
}
```

Above code not tested or anything, but should at least illustrate the algorithm.

It should produce a list of times the employee worked, one shift per line.

**EDIT**: You might need to handle edge cases, like if the employee is working from 23:45-24:00

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, a couple fixes and it works perfect!

```
<?php

$date = '10/01/2010';

$string = '000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111110000000011111111111110000000000000000000';

//convert your string in to an array
$data = str_split($string); 

$time = strtotime("$date 00:00:00"); //midnight on whatever day $date is

$workstate = 0; // zero means not working, 1 means working.
foreach($data as $index=>$value){
    // employee started working
    if ($value && !$workstate){ 
        $workstate = 1;
        echo date('h:i:s',$time) .'-';
    }
    // employee stopped working
    if ($workstate && !$value){
        $workstate = 0;
        echo date('h:i:s',$time) . PHP_EOL;
    }
    $time = strtotime('+15 minutes', $time); #increase time by 15 minutes
}

?>
```

Comment: You're welcome, but you shouldn't add a new answer to say thanks.  Comment on my answer, instead.  Also: get some reputation so you can upvote+accept my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me for your two sample strings:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$shift_strings = array(
    '000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000',
    '000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111110000000011111111111110000000000000000000'
);

$initial_time = 0; // 12AM
$now = 0; // counter
$increment = 15 * 60; // each digit = 15 minutes, but store as seconds
$offset = 0;
foreach ($shift_strings as $string) {
    echo $string, "\n";

    $shifts = preg_split('/(0+)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE |PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    foreach($shifts as $shift) {
        $start = strftime('%I:%M%P', $now * $increment);
        $now += strlen($shift);
        $end = strftime('%I:%M%P', $now * $increment);
        switch(substr($shift, 0, 1)) {
            case '0':
                echo "Offshift $start - $end\n";
                break;
            case '1':
                echo "Onshift  $start - $end\n";
                break;
            default:
                echo "Someone dun goofed, digit is ", $substr($shifts, 0, 1), "?\n";
        }
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

And the output is:

```
000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000
Offshift 12:00am - 08:00am
Onshift  08:00am - 06:00pm
Offshift 06:00pm - 12:00am

000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111110000000011111111111110000000000000000000
Offshift 12:00am - 09:30am
Onshift  09:30am - 02:00pm
Offshift 02:00pm - 04:00pm
Onshift  04:00pm - 07:15pm
Offshift 07:15pm - 12:00am
```